# Automapper flattening using child collection item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm using Automapper for Below Source to Destination Mapping. There is a Child collection with in Source Object, and I want to use the First Item of that item for mapping.

**Below is the Source and Destination Classes:**

```
class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InnerSource> InnerSources { get; set; }

}
class InnerSource
{
    public string InnerName { get; set; }
    public string InnerDesciption { get; set; }
}

class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string InnerName { get; set; }
    public string InnerDesciption { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapper Configuration:**

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(s => s.InnerSources);
cfg.CreateMap<List<InnerSource>, Destination>()
       .ForMember(d => d.InnerName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstOrDefault().InnerName))
       .ForMember(d => d.InnerDesciption, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.FirstOrDefault().InnerDesciption));
```

When I tried to map using the above configuration, it worked perfectly.

```
var source = new Source { 
            Name = "name", 
            InnerSources = new List<InnerSource> { 
                new InnerSource { InnerName = "John", InnerDesciption = "person"}
            }
        };
        var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
```

But the downside is, I had to map all properties from Source Child Collection individually.

Is there any better approach to solve the above problem?

Comment: You can add a property on the source (for `FirstOrDefault`) and use `IncludeMembers`.